# I want my submit button to console.log all the values input by the user in an array

Tags: javascript, html

**Example html:**

```
<form id="app-form">
    <label for="firstname" class="standard-label">
      First Name
      <input name="firstname" id="firstname" type="text">
     </label>    
     <label for="lastname" class="standard-label">
       Last Name
       <input name="lastname" id="lastname" type="text">
     </label>
     <input id="submit-app" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="logValues()">
</form>
```

I want clicking the submit button to call the logValues function which is below.

**JavaScript / jQuery**

```
function logValues() {
    console.log($('app-form').serializeArray());
  }
```

I want this to log an array of the updated key:values into the console when the user has completed the form.

Currently I can call the function manually and it will log an empty array, because no input has been recorded but clicking the submit button does nothing.

Comment: `'app-form'` is the buggy selector here. You need to use ID selector -- `'#app-form'`. Also, the submit button refreshes the page if you don't prevent it, so even if something is logged, you may not be able to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct approach to do this (Javascript/jQuery):

```
$('#app-form').on('submit', function(){
    var arr = $(this).serializeArray();
    console.log(arr);
    return false; //      /<-- Only, if you don't want the form to be submitted after above commands
});
```

What can be surprising, your code **did actually work**. The problem was that right after handling the *click* event, the form was being submitted, so the page was refreshed - you didn't have the time to notice the console log. Please notice, that instead of *click*, my solution handles the *submit* event - that is because then you can return boolean *false* from this function, which will stop any further actions (submitting the form, in this case).

Learn more about how it works (and why `e.preventDefault()` is not a better solution) in  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/5560928).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked and thanks for explaining your code as well!.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
function logValues() {
    console.log($('#app-form').serializeArray());
}
```

:)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo

Comment: :) really? dont new that:)

Answer (score 0):

Your error is most likely a typo.

For jQuery you have to specify an ID by prefixing the ID name with a "#".

However, you can rewrite the function to prevent the default, so that the page doesn't refresh on form submit.

```
  $(document).on('submit',function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   console.log($('#app-form').serializeArray());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code might be better to use.

```
$("#app-form").submit(function( event ) {
  console.log( $( this ).serializeArray() );
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

`event.preventDefault();` will make sure your page does not reload after the submit

As from https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Update your HTML: (Close the element with `/>`)

```
<input id="submit-app" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: `input` is a self-closing tag. `/>` isn't required; `>` is sufficient.

Comment: It's just neater.

Answer (score -2):

Once you press Submit button, you page reloads. So you don't see the console.log output - it goes erased. Go to developer mode settings and set "Preserve log". So you will be able to see you console.log output.